# Order objects based on ordering of member variables without comparator

Tags: java, sorting

Say I have an object

```
Person
  private int age;
  private String name;
```

And I want to sort them automatically using something like `Arrays.sort()` such that low ages come before high ages.

A common way to do this is with a comparator, but I with so many useful utility functions out there, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I think Comparator is the cleanest way. Is there something in particular you wanted "cleaner"?

Comment: Yes there is implement your own comparator and sent it to collections.sort

Answer (score 4):

Make your class Implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 1):

The example from [`lambdaj`](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) addresses your use case:

```
List<Person> sortedByAgePersons = sort(persons, on(Person.class).getAge());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 with Lambda:

```
personList.sort((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.age, p2.age));
```

or

```
Collections.sort(personList, (p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.age, p2.age));
```

Comment: Sry, switched to `Integer.compare(int, int)` since age is a primitive `int`. Did not realize that in the first step ...

Answer (score -1):

*Mistakes were made*

You can also implement the interface Comparable  and override the compareTo(...) method.

These ways to not guarentee it will be cleaner, but they are just different ways to compare. Using Comparator is only useful when you want to order objects in such a way that does not follow it's natural order.

Comment: equals returns a boolean, so this doesn't work at all.

Comment: Overriding `equals` does NOT change natural ordering. It's just equality. Implementing `Comparable` defines natural ordering.

Comment: Sorry. You can use equals() to manually change ordering. It does not change it automatically. It's a much messier way to write it. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No. `equals` is for equality. `Comparable` is for natural ordering. The only thing they have in common is that `equals` should be consistent with the natural ordering. That means when implmenting `Comparable` then `equals()` should be overwritten. (and therefore `hashCode()` too, because it should be consistent with `equals()`)

Comment: Thank you. What you just said is what I tried to say but utterly failed at. I eliminated the equals portion of my answer to eliminate any confusion it may cause.